# Posting message on Facebook pages

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

How to post message on Facebook pages timeline in Android?This allows the Graph API?Thank's for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of `Facebook Android SDK` [available here](http://developers.facebook.com/android/). Read the [documentation to get started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/).

Here is another [good tutorial for you information](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/462526/Easy-Facebook-Android-SDK-Simple-Tutorial).